# Multiple password attempts for Telnet connection

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

So I have the following code which establishes a Telnet connection to a virtual machine on my local machine:

```
from telnetlib import Telnet

try:
    tnet = Telnet('127.0.0.1', 2282, 3)
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed!')

# The connection has been established!
print('Success!')

for i in range(0,5):
    tnet.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tnet.write(b'password' + b'\r\n')
    tnet.write(b'v' + b'\n\r')
    tnet.close()

    break
```

The connection succeeds, but I need to be able to access the machine from code! I will replace the 'password' with a user's attempt, but I can't tell if the attempt has even worked and if it **hasn't** then how can I retry another attempt?

**EDIT: **

I tested the Telnet connection from my terminal on the host machine and the terminal output is like this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 2282
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Password: 

Login incorrect
admin1-VirtualBox login: admin1
Password:
```

So if I check first for `read_until(b'Password: ')` and it fails, should I catch it and create a loop containg more `read_until` statements? Or is there a much neater way to do this.

A previous way I thought about doing this was attempting a whole new telnet connection every time it was wrong in a `while` loop

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a line of the what the console returns (string) and place in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341443/how-do-i-get-a-line-of-the-what-the-console-returns-string-and-place-in-a-vari)

Comment: You can use `read_until` with a timeout to look for the regular prompt. If it doesn't arrive, you didn't login.

Comment: @quamrana I just looked up the timeout as well, but what would I be checking for if the first `read_until` failed? I'm not looking for a single failure, if the first password attempt fails I need to use another attempt

Comment: Well, read the documentation on `read_until` and see what you can come up with. If you have a question about it, then feel free to ask a different question on this site.