# IRC Client in Python; not a IRC Bot

Tags: python, regex, multithreading, module, irc

I've searched extensively on this and only came up with bot specific clients. I know they're basically the same, but for what I want to do I just can't figure it out.

I am trying to program a python client, that is pure and simple on it's face. For example when run from the command line it will immediately connect invisibly and then print "say: " after it has established the connection. (username, server, etc. are already set) It will wait until the user has pressed -return/enter- and then it will send the message and then retrieve the messages that it has been logging to an array and print the last 8 lines/array values.

So the user will only see the messages on the channel, and be able to send messages. My issue is figuring out how to strip everything but the messages. I'm so sorry if I seem like I'm wanting someone to do this for me. I've looked and looked but I can't figure it out. Do I have to use a IRC module? I'm pretty sure that I'll end up using regex somehow, but I'm stumped. Thanks guys for reading my silly question!

```
import sys
import socket
import string

HOST="irc.freenode.net"
PORT=6667
NICK="MauBot"
IDENT="maubot"
REALNAME="MauritsBot"
readbuffer=""

s=socket.socket( )
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
s.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))

while 1:
    readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(1024)
    temp=string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
    readbuffer=temp.pop( )

    for line in temp:
        line=string.rstrip(line)
        line=string.split(line)

        if(line[0]=="PING"):
            s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
```

Comment: Look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/irc

Comment: It's pretty difficult to connect to anything 'invisibly'.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. It couldn't find the module "setuptools." Thanks for the ultra fast reply! ^-^

Comment: I meant that the user wouldn't see the MOTD, PONGs, etc. when I said invisibly. =)

Comment: If it can't find `setuptools`, get that from pypi as well: [pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

Comment: Got the module installed, but now it's throwing more errors when I try running the sample irc client script: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zUiAl.png

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an IRC server using `Telnet`.
There are libraries in Python to accomplish this.

See these links for more information:

> > [Python Telnet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528831/python-telnet-connection)
>
> > [Using Telnet in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/python-using-telnet)
>
> > [Python Doco: 20.14. telnetlib — Telnet client](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html)

Once you have connected to the IRC server, you can:

1. Output whatever commands you need to in the telnet session (such as login credentials).
2. Join a channel.
3. Write out the lines that you need to.