# Make telnet communication using python

Tags: python, telnet, ethernet

It is my first question here :D

I have to send some commands from my personal computer (Linux-Red Hat) to a server (Robot Controller). I saw that the controller have a Ethernet protocol that allows sending commands using telnet communication.

My question: is it possible to make telnet connection, send commands and read the output using python? If it is, can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528831/python-telnet-connection?rq=1). It has sample code.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Have you tried to connect with the telnetlib library? We can't help unless you have a clear problem to solve. Your question doesn't explain what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python they have telnetlib, which allows telnet communication. I'm pretty sure that this is what you're looking for. You can find the docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html Here is a basic way to logon to a windows server and get the directory listing (Courtesy of the docs pages above)

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = "username"
password = "password"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("dir\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```